Is it possible to filter woocommerce product tags programmatically?
I am using tags for some product display filtering, grouping them into specific groups. At the same time I am displaying product tags on product pages for SEO purposes so I end up with a bunch of tags that are not that good looking for the customer. Is it possible to programmatically remove them before displaying for the customer?
ChatGPT is offering a filter that does not exist or I can not find documentation for it:
function exclude_specific_tags_from_display($tags, $product) {
    // Define tags to exclude
    $excluded_tags = array('shop-by-birthday-gift-tote-bag');
    
    // Filter out the excluded tags
    $tags = array_filter($tags, function($tag) use ($excluded_tags) {
        return !in_array($tag->slug, $excluded_tags);
    });

    return $tags;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_tags', 'exclude_specific_tags_from_display', 10, 2);

And this of course does not work as expected.

This worked:
function filter_product_tags_with_debug($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy) {
if ($taxonomy == 'product_tag') {
    // Define the unwanted tag slugs (more than one tag)
    $unwanted_tag_slugs = ['themostunwanted', 'shop-by-birthday-gift-tote-bag', 'yetanotherunwantedtag'];

    // Filter out the unwanted tags from the array of terms
    foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
        // Check if the term's slug is in the unwanted list
        if (in_array($term->slug, $unwanted_tag_slugs)) {
            unset($terms[$key]);
        }
    }

    // Log the filtered terms to the browser console for debugging
 //   console_log($terms);
}
return $terms;

}
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'filter_product_tags_with_debug', 10, 3);
